# SSIS Truncation Error on 'float' (DT_R8) Data Type

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package (VS2019) migrating data from an Access data source (ODBC) to a MSSQL (2012, ADO.NET) destination.  There are many tables, containing many float fields all running without issue; however, on one particular float field the following error occurs:

> Error: 0x384 at ImpellerData, ODBC Source [64]: Open Database
>   Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: '01S07'. Native Error Code:
>   13. [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Fractional truncation on column number 20 (D2aRefdiameter)

MSAccess Type = Number [Field Size = Double]

MSSQL Type = float, null

I've done a review of the data in MSAccess and don't notice anything out of the ordinary.

The largest value is: 614

The smallest value is: 0.00328

I've tried googling on truncation errors but, most of the results are in relation to text fields.
I realize this error may just be saying that due the converted value might be *slightly* different than the source value, which is fine but, I don't see a way to ignore truncation errors for this data type.

Any suggestions about how to get around this issue or things to look into will be very much appreciated.

I've posted what I think the applicable parts are above but, if more information is needed, just let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations, that's an SSIS error I've not seen before. 1) You are using the ODBC Data source (based on the error message) - is there a reason you selected that (and the accompanying driver)? Does it behave the same way if you switch over to an OLEDB/JET/ACE driver?  2) If you modify the source from a table to a query and explicitly cast `D2aRefdiameter` to a string type, does that solve the problem?  3) You can add an OnTruncation error path out of your source by ... double clicking it and looking for an Error tab. If not, it's a right click advanced editor. Then you can exam the bad data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I used the Jet driver as you suggested in #1 and it worked without issue.  Not sure what the issue was with ODBC but, happy to be moving on with it working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via comments, Beeker switched to using JET driver instead of ODBC driver and that resolved the issue.

Comment promoted to answer

> You are using the ODBC Data source (based on the error message) - is there a reason you selected that (and the accompanying driver)? Does it behave the same way if you switch over to an OLEDB/JET/ACE driver? 2) If you modify the source from a table to a query and explicitly cast D2aRefdiameter to a string type, does that solve the problem? 3) You can add an OnTruncation error path out of your source by ... double clicking it and looking for an Error tab. If not, it's a right click advanced editor. Then you can exam the bad data